# Python: turn tuples into array

Tags: python-2.7, tuples, sparse-matrix

Currently, I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[(0, 0.13), (323, 0.72), (812, 0.35), ..., (2127, 0.44)]
```

The tuples are ordered by their first element: 0 -> 323 -> 812 -> ...

I want to turn this list of tuples into an array (or a sparse matrx), with the first element of each tuple being the second element's array index:

```
[0.13, 0, ..., 0, 0.72, 0, ...,  0, 0.35, 0, ...]
```

And to fill the end of this array with 0s to extend it into a certain length.

Can anyone provide a fast implementation of the function above in python?

I currently use a dictionary to accomplish this procedure, and it's very slow for large arrays.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create an array with 0 as placeholders for those indices that are missing; so between 0.13 and 0.72, there are 322 zeros - is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preallocate an array of zeros and then fill in the supplied numbers:

```
def expand_sparse_array(inp):
    length = (inp[-1][0]+1) # index of last element + 1
    out = [0]*length

    for (idx, val) in inp:
        out[idx] = val

    return out
```

For example:

```
>>> expand_sparse_array([(0, 0.13), (3, 0.72), (5, 0.35), (10, 0.44)])
[0.13, 0, 0, 0.72, 0, 0.35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.44]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you require:

```
results = []
for k,i in list_of_tuples:
  while k > len(results):
     results.append(0)
  results.append(i)
```

Here is a sample run, given an input of `[(0, 12), (5, 43), (10, 1)]`, there result is:

```
>>> i = []
>>> for k,v in t:
...    while k > len(i):
...       i.append(0)
...    i.append(v)
...
>>> i
[12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```